# Dockerfile if else condition with external arg for FROM

Tags: docker, dockerfile

how to do use FROM if else statement with external ARG. For example in Dockerfile:

```
    ARG MYARG

    if MYARG='true'{
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803
    }
    elseif MYARG='false'{
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: it doesn't work so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no if/else syntax currently in the Dockerfile. With BuildKit, you can take advantage of building only the dependencies in a multi stage build to use the following syntax:

```
ARG BUILD_VERSION=1
FROM alpine AS base
RUN …

FROM base AS branch-version-1
RUN touch version1

FROM base AS branch-version-2
RUN touch version2

FROM branch-version-${BUILD_VERSION} AS after-condition

FROM after-condition 
RUN …
```

This is described in more detail at: https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/advanced-multi-stage-build-patterns-6f741b852fae

Comment: `ARG DOCKER_SOURCE_IMAGE`
`FROM registry/images:${DOCKER_SOURCE_IMAGE}`